# How to I create action strips for shape key animations?

Tags: shape-keys

I've created a face mesh with 52 ARkit shapekeys and want to save different animations as **Actions** so I can use the **NLA** editor.

The problem I'm facing is Shape key keyframes don't appear in the Action editor but they do appear in the timeline and dope sheet.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Dope Sheet* you need to switch to *Shape Key Editor* and you'll be able to push a *NLA* strip:

[image]